# Separate logs for each ActiveMQ port (TransportConnector)

Tags: activemq-classic

Assume I have at least 2 transport connectors. I would like to have logs for port `61616` and port `61617` to write to their own logs so I might have a log called `61616-nio.log` and `61617-stomp.log`. I would want all connections made/failed errors/warnings that are specific to that `transportConnector` to go into the log. How does one go about doing that?

I am using ActiveMQ "Classic" 5.15.2 on CentOS. I am locked into this release.

```xml
<broker>
  ...
  <transportConnectors>
    <transportConnector name="nio" uri="nio://0.0.0.0:61616"/>  
    <transportConnector name="stomp" uri="stomp://0.0.0.0:61617"/>  
  </<transportConnectors>
  ...
</broker>
```

After looking at docs and posts I have not seen the answer I am looking for. It may be staring me in the face, but I'm not seeing it.

Comment: I would want all connections made/failed errors/warnings that are specific to that transportconnector to go into the log.

Comment: There's the `TransportLogger` which is mentioned briefly in [the documentation](https://activemq.apache.org/tcp-transport-reference), but it looks like it will just log requests and responses. I'm not sure it will log everything you're interested in, but it's worth a shot.

Answer (score 0):

The transportConnector has settings to wire in a LogWriter. The default behavior (iirc) is to have a separate log per connection. You should be parse that log in order to map that back to transportConnector.

ref: https://github.com/apache/activemq/blob/main/activemq-broker/src/main/java/org/apache/activemq/transport/TransportLogger.java

Alternatively, you can implement your own LogWriter, add it as a service and wire it into the transportConnector config via the *logWriterName* property.

ref: https://activemq.apache.org/tcp-transport-reference
ref: https://github.com/apache/activemq/blob/main/activemq-broker/src/main/java/org/apache/activemq/transport/logwriters/DefaultLogWriter.java

Comment: Looks promising. I will take a look and see how to get implemented. Thanks.